# Zend Framework, Returning class methods from model

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-framework-modules

I have a Model which I would like to use all variables in a drop down lis on a form.

```
protected $_scheduledTime;
protected $_isLive;
protected $_isQueued;
protected $_url;
```

I was hoping, something like this would work, but it doesn't

```
public function getMethods() {
    $methods = getclass_methods($this);
    return $methods;
}
```

Calling this returns this fatal error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function getclass_methods()

What I want to achieve is an automatically updated form options when I update the model (which, could be quite frequently)

I might have answered my own question, in that I would build an array in the model that returns upon a call... but if there is already a method that can do this, then it would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `$class_vars = get_class_vars(get_class($this));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get_declared_classes() // gives you all declared classes
get_class_methods() // gives you all methods of class
get_class_vars() // gives you properties of the class
get_object_vars() // gives you propertis of an object
get_parent_class()  // gives you parent class of the current class
```

Answer (score 1):

The function is [get_class_methods](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php), not getclass_methods (missing an '_')

Comment: Woops, :$. do you know if a way to return the protected variables? (get_class_methods will work, but only after some modification... whereas getting the protected variables will work straight off)

Comment: oh, and thank you for the correction. this is the correct answer for my question.

Comment: I think you have to use [get_class_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php). But it will only return the properties that can be accessed from the current scope